# Создание сетевых пакетов на локальной машине с возможностью изменить IP назначения и отправителя

Tags: c, windows, сеть

Вообщем, пишу программу на Си для обхода NAT (с помощью VPS, будет работать как обратный прокси, но подключение будет совершать компьютер), клиент делаю под Windows, и передо мной встала проблема, когда от VPS приходит сообщение о том, что у него запрос, мне надо искуственным путём "пустить" в компьютер TCP пакет, в котором я руками укажу IP назначения и IP отправителя.

Хотел бы сделать это без прибегания к NDIS.

Надеюсь понятно объяснил свою проблему.

Comment: Если клиент за NAT то он может получить только ответ в пределах своей TCP сессии, т.е. строго с того же ip и порта на который он обращался. Пакет с другими параметрами слать бесполезно, NAT не пропустит

Comment: О чём я и говорю, здесь прикол как VPN, пакет инкапсулируется в TCP пакет, в котором в данных указаны нужные данные, такие как IP и т.д, этот TCP пакет придёт ко мне на компьютер, и там я должен будет создать искуственный пакет, что-бы для компьютера всё казалось будто NAT'а и нету

Comment: но ваш сервер сможет отрыть любое соединение только от своего ip. так что передавать с клиента ip и порт отправителя пакета бесполезно. Он только должен сообщить с кем соединяться. после этого сервер открывает нужное соединение совершенно стандартными средствами от своего ip и пробрасывает трафик идущий внутри сессии обартно клиенту. Либо, если нужны входящие соединения, открывает опять же на своем ip динамический порт и сообщает его клиенту что бы тот мог его кому то сообщить. собственно все это обеспечивает протокол Socks